# How to send traffic to a specific IP address via a specific interface?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openssh

On a Debian Stretch VM (running in VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host), I would like to connect via SSH to a specific remote host (let's call it `myServer`, with IP `12.34.56.78`). To do so, I'm using my Android smartphone as a USB modem, which works fine : I can reach the internet and generate some 'ping' and HTTP/HTTPS traffic, and even open an SSH connection with a command like :

```
ssh httqm@12.34.56.78 -b a.b.c.d -p portNumber -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

NB: `a.b.c.d` is the dynamic IP address assigned to my USB interface upon connection

To make things easier, I'd like to have all these settings in `~/.ssh/config` so that I'll just have to type `ssh myServer` :

```
Host myServer
    HostName 12.34.56.78
    Port portNumber
#   BindAddress a.b.c.d     <== commented because this is part of the question
#   BindInterface usb0      <== same as above
    User httqm
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

- I can uncomment the `BindAddress` line and specify the IP address, which works but provides no gain compared to the full SSH command line since `a.b.c.d` is dynamic
- using the [BindInterface](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#BindInterface) option (without `BindAddress`) fails with error message :

  ```
  ~/.ssh/config: line 154: Bad configuration option: bindinterface
  ~/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
  ```

This error message is expected since the `BindInterface` directive was introduced by Openssh 7.7 (https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) whereas I have :

```
$ dpkg -l openssh-client
openssh-client      1:7.4p1-10+deb9u6
```

To workaround this, I'm considering several solutions :

1. define a route with `ip route ...` commands so that everything aimed at `myServer` goes through the USB interface. So far, I've tried commands like this :

   ```
   ip route add to 12.34.56.78 protocol static dev usb0
   ```

The command itself returns no error, but I can't open an SSH connection with `ssh myServer`, I can't even ping it.

2. define a Netfilter rule so that all traffic to/from 12.34.56.78 goes through the usb0 interface. Would that even work ? Should I investigate this solution ?
3. upgrade `openssh-client` from backports if available

Can you please explain which would / wouldn't work (and why) ? What would you suggest to reach my goal which is to connect to my SSH host with a short command line such as `ssh myServer` considering my source address is dynamic ?